# bootstrap row-cols-sm-1 does not work with cards. Two cards appear on cell screen when it should be 1

Tags: css, row

Here is my code

```
<div class="row row-cols-lg-3 row-cols-md-2 row-cols-sm-1 g-4">
  <div class="col">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
           <div class="card-body">
           <h5 class="card-title">...</h5>
            <p class="...</p>
           </div>
       </div> 
  </div>
```

As you can see `row-cols-sm-1` is set to one, but when setting the view to a phone in Google Chrome's dev tools, the page shows two cards per row when it should only be one. If I remove the sm-1 class and put md-1 then it will show one card per row, but I really want md to be set to two.
[image: picture of the cards on chrome]

Comment: Try to add   row-cols-1

Comment: I did this ```row row-cols-1 row-cols-lg-3 rows-cols-md-2 row-cols-sm-1 g-4``` and it just skips the md-2 size. Im totally new to css so Im probably not doing this right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your example

- <576px row-cols-1  one card for this size
- ≥576px row-cols-sm-1  one card for this size
- ≥768px rows-cols-md-2 two cards
- ≥992px row-cols-lg-3 three cards
- ≥1200px three cards

Here an example with use a class in each column. If you use a framework you will loop and write one simple class. **col-md-6 col-lg-4**

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="card ">card</div>
        </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="card ">card</div>
        </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="card ">card</div>
        </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="card ">card</div>
        </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="card ">card</div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can I get 3 cards for large screens, two for medium, and 1 for small ones like cell phones??

Comment: i tried this but it still shows two rows on a phone? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm so surprised that nobody is able to answer such a trivial question!

Because you're missing this meta in the head:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```